# PHP function descriptions as I type in Notepad++

Tags: php, notepad++

Is there a plugin for Notepad++ which would allow me to see functions including parameters/returns as I type?

For example, if i type "implode(", I'd see:

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
```

**Update:** Wow, I'm surprised so many other people were as interested in this as me.  The take-home lesson for me was to always explore all the Settings options!

Comment: I also upvoted, because strangely enough, I didn't know this before. I just looked it up to provide the answer - my exclamation points are mostly due to my own surprise and shock that I never knew this before.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need a plugin! 5.0 and above have this already.

Go to *Settings -> Preferences*, then go to the *Backup/Auto-Completion* tab, and you'll find it at the bottom! Check the box for function parameters hint as well.

You'll get exactly what you've asked for, as long as it knows the file is PHP.

Comment: @babonk: If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to _accept_ it when able.

Comment: O.o : Shocked, how could such a useful built in feature go un-noticed. But oh well, most of us users of Notepad++ never read the manual. We just jump in as something similar but alot better then notepad. XD

Comment: Will do, just couldn't accept right away.  @Tesserex I also want to thank you for getting me to finally look at all the Settings options.. I really improved my coding setup

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit floored that I've been using N++ for years and never bothered to find this. So thanks for making me look!

Comment: Is there a way to show it again? Like Ctrl+p in PHPStorm

Comment: Just delete the left parenthesis and type it back in to redisplay.

Answer (score 2):

maybe, plugin **Auto completion for custom PHP classes (ACCPC)** is what you're mean.

basic info:
Show an overview over your classes' attributes & methods in a nice popup!

A popup window appears after typing the `"->"` or `"::"` behind a class or an instantiated object variable which displays all attributes and methods of it's class.

more information:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/accpc/

---

maybe this answer can helpful too:
**Get parameter hints from Editing the API XML file**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12609240/2427906

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it in Notepad++'s documentation site found here

http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/

The auto complete section can be found here

http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual//editing/auto-completion