# check function definition php

Tags: php, function, notepad++, definition

I want to check the function definition of in a php code. I am using notepad++ text editor. The same thing we can do in visual studio. Putting the cursor over the function name and hitting F12, and you will be navigated to function definition. I've googled it but can't find the desired result. Any body can help me?

Edit

In ([PHP function descriptions as I type in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380403/php-function-descriptions-as-i-type-in-notepad)) this post user has asked about the intellisense feature of notepad++ which I already have. What I need is that, e.g if I am in abc.php and here I am calling a function 'abc();', which is defined in some xyz.php. Now is there any way in notepad++ that by pressing some short cut key or plugin that I need to install, which will take me to xyz.php->abc(){}. I think I might be clear this time

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function descriptions as I type in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380403/php-function-descriptions-as-i-type-in-notepad)

Comment: if you want to change your editor, `sublime text 3` works with F12

Comment: forgot to mention, you need `open folder` in sublime instead of opening multiple file

Comment: Perhaps there are some plugins that does it, one of them may be the php class inspector, but I'm not sure if they either are currently "official" plugins or just user scratches. Moreover, such an advanced binding requires notepad++ to manually inspect many files which should be included in a **project**, which is the most common method used by almost any kind of "advanced" IDE (like eclipse, visual studio and so on). In a nutshell I don't think notepad++ can do it, unless there are some really advanced plugins that does it for you, but it requires significant work to make a perfect plugin.

Comment: @briosheje but I think its a very common thing that every developer has to come across. As I migrated from .net to php framework I am finding it very difficult to check that how the function is exactly working. To mention I am new to notepad++ and php. So is there any way that I can achieve this

Comment: @user3567832 : notepad++ is just a generic editor, as far as I know it probably can pretend to know the parameters of a function by looking at the current file itself, but how is it supposed to guess that it has to find another file to load a class and find a method? If you are migrating from .net and the intellisense for user-defined classes is a must for you I think the fastest solution you have is to use eclipse with the PHP plugin or any advanced php editor (there are many online), but I don't think notepad++ will be able to accomplish such advanced tasks.

Comment: Also, for reference purposes, check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278467/notepad-intellisense-for-user-defined-functions . In a nutshell, the auto-completion is located in the plugins/apis folder, where you can find php.xml, where everything is defined.